# Which Installation suite support Multiple packages?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, suite

we are having multiple components in our application which can be installed separately. Parent application can include that component .

Now we want better Installation suite which can consume another package. We check Installshield suites but don't seem that it can include another suite.

Which Installation suite is having this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Other options could be the [suite support from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html) or the [Burn bootstrapper from Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/). Depends on the complete list of requirements you have and how much time you have available to learn new tools.